# NDK SurfaceView redraw got broken display on screen rotate

Tags: android, opengl, surfaceview

I am using SurfaceView with ndk+openGL, when press screen rotate button of the emulator,
i received SurfaceChanged event from SurfaceHolder.Callback, then i post a redraw message via Handler, and the Handler redraws the screen with new display metrics via JNI native code, but the display is broken, as the picture shows.

I sure that the native OpenGL drawing code already draws one frame, after press rotate button and before screen rotation finish, but don't know why the display is broken.

I'm not so familiar with android, could someone help me. thanks.

EDIT:
when i make some touch events to trigger new frames, the display got fixed.
so i'm thinking is there a rotate finish event, so i can force draw one frame to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your post with the "native OpenGL drawing code"?

Comment: the codebase is large, i couldn't post it here, but i can explain the flow. it's just like a simple opengl app, Make eglContext current, drawing, and swap buffer. may be i need some calls to lock/unlock the SurfaceView buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

Override the `surfaceRedrawNeeded` method of SurfaceHolder.Callback2, it will be called after rotate finished.